# Using pdo_dblib to connect to the sybase failed

Tags: php, pdo, sybase

I want to use PDO to connect to a Sybase using PHP `pdo_dblib`. This is what I have done:

```
$conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$db_host:$db_port;dbname=$db_name","$login","$password");
```

It shows me `SQL Null error`. I don't know how to get it right. I have checked the php info, and the pdo_dblib is there.

```
PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib: Flavour
enabled: freetds
```

by the way, is the database port needed? Before this, I didn't put the database port number, plus now I'm still unable to get the port number.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to find the cause of the error

Step1: Connecting using telnet.

```
xxx@ubuntuvbox:~$ telnet 10.1.1.1 5000
Trying 10.1.1.1...
Connected to 10.1.1.1.
```

Step2: Configure FreeTDS

Edit freetds.conf, located in /etc/freetds/ (Ubuntu 11.10)

```
[global]
    # TDS protocol version
    tds version = 5.0
    text size = 64512
```

Step3: Connecting using FreeTDS

```
xxx@ubuntuvbox:~$ sqsh -S 10.1.1.1:5000 -Usa
sqsh-2.1 Copyright (C) 1995-2001 Scott C. Gray
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
For more information type '\warranty'
Password: 
Msg 2401, Level 11, State 2
Server 'XXXXXX'
Character set conversion is not available between client character set 'utf8'
and server character set 'cp850'.
No conversions will be done.
1> select * from .....
```

Step4: Connecting using FreeTDS with PHP

Check this...

```
$dbh = new PDO ('dblib:host=10.1.1.1:5000;dbname=databasename','sa','password');
```